# Detectar id de um elemento da DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em VueJS/Quasar e preciso descobrir o id de um determinado elemento utilizando o `getElementById`, como faço isso em VueJS??

Comment: VueJS é JavaScript. Podes usar na mesma `.getElementById`. Mas seria interessante saber mais sobre o teu código para responder melhor.

Comment: Já consegui achar uma solução utilizando `(item, index)` no `v-for` e passando ele como parâmetro no método de captura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No vue.js se utiliza o v-for pode utilizar a propriedade index.